# Swagger/Swashbuckle + IdentityServer4 Implicit Flow: 401 Error after successful login?

Tags: oauth, swagger, identityserver4, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am trying to implement OAuth to one of my companies' projects and can't resolve the following problem.

We used `IdentityServer4` for implementing our own Authorization Server, which works fine so far. The resource I want to protect with OAuth is a WebApi utilizing `Swagger/Swashbuckle`.

I followed the `IdentityServer4 QuickStartExamples` to configure the server and this tutorial [Secure Web APIs with Swagger, Swashbuckle, and OAuth2 (part 2)](http://knowyourtoolset.com/2015/08/secure-web-apis-with-swagger-swashbuckle-and-oauth2-part-2 for configuring Swagger/Swashbuckle).

I have a dummy-action which does nothing else than returning a string, that works as expected.

When I decorate the action with `[Authorize]`, a little red icon appears in swagger-ui, indicating that I have to log in to access this method. The Login process works fine: I am redirected to the Quickstart-UI, can login with the testuser "Bob", and I am redirected to swagger-ui after a successful login. 
The problem: After the successful login, I still get an 401 error, stating "Authorization has been denied for this request."

I can see that a bearer token is returned by my IdentityServer in swagger-ui, so I guess this part working fine and the problem seems to be swagger/swashbuckle.

Is there maybe anything else I have to do with the token? In the tutorials I read so far, the swagger config is modified as I did it (see below) and that's it, so I guess swagger/swashbuckle should handle this - but maybe I miss out something?

SwaggerConfig.cs:

```
c.OAuth2("oauth2")
    .Description("OAuth2 Implicit Grant")
    .Flow("implicit") //also available: password, application (=client credentials?)
    .AuthorizationUrl("http://localhost:5000/connect/authorize")
    .TokenUrl("http://localhost:5000/connect/token")
    .Scopes(scopes =>
    {
        scopes.Add("My.Web.Api", "THE Api");

    });

    // etc. .....

    c.OperationFilter<AssignOAuth2SecurityRequirements>();

    // etc. .....

c.EnableOAuth2Support(
    clientId: "swaggerui",
    clientSecret: "secret",
    realm: "dummyrealm",
    appName: "Swagger UI"

);
```

Filter for Authorize Attribute in SwaggerConfig.cs:

```
public class AssignOAuth2SecurityRequirements : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        // Determine if the operation has the Authorize attribute
        var authorizeAttributes = apiDescription
            .ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AuthorizeAttribute>();

        if (!authorizeAttributes.Any())
            return;

        // Initialize the operation.security property
        if (operation.security == null)
            operation.security = new List<IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>>();

        // Add the appropriate security definition to the operation
        var oAuthRequirements = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
    {
        { "oauth2", new [] { "My.Web.Api" } }
    };

        operation.security.Add(oAuthRequirements);
    }
}
```

IdentityServer api config:

```
new ApiResource("My.Web.Api", "THE  Api")
```

IdentityServer client config:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "swaggerui",
    ClientName = "Swagger UI",

    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
    AllowedCorsOrigins = { "http://localhost:5858" },

    ClientSecrets =
    {
        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
    },

    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5858/swagger/ui/o2c-html" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5858/swagger/ui/o2c-html" },

    AllowedScopes =
    {
        "My.Web.Api"
    }
```

Screenshot of redirection after login:
[image: Screenshot from redirect after login, still 401]

Comment: Check the logs on identityserver it should tell you why its not letting you in.

Comment: after that try this  [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]

Comment: The Logs state that I am logged in after being redirected to swagger ui. When I click "Try it out!", nothing is logged anymore. I don't know how to get [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")], working with swashbuckle. I can't call services.AddJwtBearer(...) as suggested by the Microsoft Docs, as I only have the SwaggerConfig.cs and no Startup.cs.

Comment: I also cannot call   c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new ApiKeyScheme)... as suggested here https://ppolyzos.com/2017/10/30/add-jwt-bearer-authorization-to-swagger-and-asp-net-core/ for the same reason. In SwaggerConfig.cs, where I call c.OAuth2("oauth2") ..., there is also nothing Bearer-Related I could call.

Answer (score 0):

When using .NET Core (but it would appear that this question is for .NET Framework) I also encountered this same problem.  It was solved by ensuring that in the Configure method of Startup you have UseAuthentication before UseAuthorization

(source https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-3.1)